# Projecting files from one folder to another

Tags: linux, file, debian, directory

---

I would like to have a part of apache configs in my local folder.

It's necessary to automate subdomains creation.

Is it possible to project all files from my local folder into `/etc/apche2/sites-available/` folder under the Debian linux?

I. e. don't create symbolic link for a every new file, but just make somthing simple 8-)

It's must be looked like that:

```
LOCAL FOLDER                           SITES-AVAILABLE

f1.conf                                s-a1.conf
f2.conf                                s-a2.conf
f3.conf                                s-a3.conf
                                       f1.conf
                                       f2.conf
                                       f3.conf
```

## Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry, im found solution for me. Just create symbolic link right into apache config folder.

`/etc/apche2/sites-available/@local-folder/`

Apache has eat it 8-)

But quostion is still open. Cous some people may be need it not for apache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `man mount`:

> `mount --bind olddir newdir`
>
> After this call the same contents are accessible in two  places. One  can  also  remount  a single file (on a single file).

In your case it would be:

```
sudo mount --bind /etc/apche2/sites-available/ ~/my/local/folder/
```

Make sure `~/my/local/folder/` is empty before you do `mount`.